# Linked module shows up as unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two local node packages, let's call them `pack1` and `pack2`. Now, `pack2` depends on `pack1`, but `pack1` is not published to npm, instead it's just linked locally (using `npm link`). `pack2` is also linked to make sure I'm using the latest local changes. However, `npm list -g` gives me something like this:

```
├─┬ pack1@1.0.0 -> /path/to/pack1
... many lines ...
├─┬ pack2@0.1.4 -> /path/to/pack2
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY pack1@1.0.0
```

Weirdly, as `pack1` is actually a yeoman generator, and doing `yo pack1` works, so it is getting picked up.

Trying to do `npm install` in `pack2` throws an error saying `pack1` is not found.

How can I get this to work? I feel like I'm missing something super basic.

Comment: Can you give the precise `npm link` commands you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following sequence of `npm link` commands.

```
$ cd pack1
$ npm link          # make this linkable

$ cd pack2
$ npm link pack1    # bring in pack1 via link--did you do this??
```

To check that all is set up correctly:

```
$ cd pack2
$ ls -l node_modules/pack1
```

This should display a symbolic link to pack1. If that is there, and pack1 can nevertheless not be required, then there may be a problem with pack1, such as no `index.js` file or `main` entry in package.json.

Comment: Seems like running `npm link pack1` in `pack2` fixed the unmet dependency, but I still can't `require('pack1')`, I get "cannot find module" :(

Comment: I don't have a `project`, I only have `pack1` and `pack2`. It's already in `package.json` of `pack2`, which is where I'm trying to use it.

Comment: Yep, the issue was with the `main` directive in `package.json`. Yeoman was picking it up because it doesn't look for that property, it just hardcodes to `generators/app/index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to:

1. *Uninstall it completely* from "pack2" (`npm uninstall pack1`)
2. `npm link pack1` from "pack2", and then
3. Run `npm install pack1` in "pack2"

Every other combination of steps did not work, and I did not find the uninstall or reinstall documented anywhere. Hope this helps anyone else running into this problem.

Comment: `npm install pack1` in pack2 wiped out my link and install the default one from the repo..